# Regular Expression to match digits in specific line

Tags: regex

I have the following String:

```
Apple---a---1---d---2
Pear---b---3---e---4
Melon---c---9---f---8
```

My input is a fruit, and I would like to pick all the digits from that specific row. For example:

```
input: Apple
output: 1 2

input: Pear
output: 3 4
```

I can do this with 2 regular expressions: one to get the line and one to get the digits from the line, but is there a way to get this in one?

Thanks!

---

**Edit**

I see that I have to be more specific. The question: is it possible to catch repetition inside one pattern? I have a match on the line Pear, can I somehow catch the digits inside in that line? 
The example above is not from real life, I don't want to implement it in any language, it doesn't matter that it is a fruit or not, it is just an abstract question with a simple example.

For the example above, I've created this:

```
(?:Pear)(?:[^;\d])*(\d)(?:[^;\d])*(\d)
```

But as you can see I reached my goal with repetition of the group

```
(?:[^;\d])*
```

And if I try to dothis with a multiplier, it will only catch the last number, and I want all the numbers. As far as I know, there is no solution to this, but stackoverflow doesn't let me delete this question.
I'm using regex101 for checking.

Comment: How do you know it is a fruit? Is your first regex a list of known fruits, like:
/(Apple|Pear|Melon|Orange)/i

Will there be only two digits? If so, you might write:
/(apple|pear|melon|orange).*(\d+).*(\d+)/i

The name of the fruit will be in $1, the first digit in $2, the second in $3.

Comment: Please show your attempts and specify the regex engine.

Comment: What is the language/tool?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on `---`, i.e.:

```
[y.strip() for y in x.split("---")]
```

---

```
s = """
Apple---a---1---d---2
Pear---b---3---e---4
Melon---c---9---f---8
"""


def fruit_game(fruit):
    out = ""
    for x in s.split():
        parts = [y.strip() for y in x.split("---")]
        if parts[0] == fruit :
            out = "{}\n{} {}".format(parts[0], parts[2], parts[4])
            break
    if out :
        return(out)
    else:
        return("Fruit not found")
while 1:  
    fruit = input("Choose a fruit:")
    print( fruit_game(fruit) )
```

---

[Live Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/Q8o) (Turn Interactive mode **ON**)

Answer (score 0):

A perl way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;

my @fruits = (
    'Apple---a---1---d---2',
    'Pear---b---3---e---4',
    'Melon---c---9---f---8',
);
my %fruits;
/^(\w+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)/ and @{$fruits{$1}} = ($2, $3) for @fruits;
while (1) {
    my $in = <>;
    chomp $in;
    last if $in eq 'exit';
    say "@{$fruits{$in}}" if exists $fruits{$in};
}
```

**Running:**

```
perl test.pl 
Pear
3 4
blah
Melon
9 8
exit
```